# React Router Dom v4 handle browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-dom

How do I disable a browser back button click from user using `react-router-dom` v4?

I am showing a modal on a page and when the user presses browser back button then the user is taken to the previous screen, instead I want to simply close the modal.

I tried doing this

```
onBackButtonEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    // the user shouldn't be able to move backward or forward  
}
componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = this.onBackButtonEvent;
}
```

But this doesn't prevent the user from going backward or forward. Is there a way to handle this via `react-router-dom`?

I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: There is no way you could fit your modal into a new route, e.g. `/myroute/edit`, and when the user clicks the back button he gets taken to `/myroute` and the modal is closed automatically?

Comment: But this is exactly what I want to avoid, I don't want to create new route. I mean, a modal isn't supposed to have a different route, right?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Okay. What if the modal has a transparent background and I want to show the user the same background when the modal is active? How do I render the new modal on top of the current route just so that the user has a feel that they haven't left the current route?

Comment: Just put it outside of the `Switch` so `/myroute` and `/myroute/edit` can be rendered at the same time.

Comment: Okay. I will try that.

Comment: [I created a simple example maybe you can use for inspiration](https://codesandbox.io/s/3x534mkz5p)

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It certainly did in a way. There is one problem with this approach. The content inside ModalComponent is dynamic not limited to variable but the JSX itself. And the content depends upon from where the ModalComponent is called. This is why I wanted to disable back button in the first place and render the ModalComponent from within other Parent Component so I could fill the contents inside the Modal from the Parent and then read it via this.props.children. I hope that makes senses.

Comment: Alright. I updated the answer.

Comment: You can check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475147/4574879

Answer (score 6):

I know this question's a little old but I stumbled on it while looking for the answer myself. There's no clean way to "disable" the back button but to enable the user to only  close the modal when clicking the browser back button I found this to work.

Simply pass the history to your modal component in props and call the below on the `componentWillUnmount` function.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.history.goForward();
}
```

This will seamlessly force the browser to stay on the same page but close the modal (assuming it's a class component).

UPDATE: If using functional components, the above componentWillUnmount function looks like the hook below.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
            props.history.goForward();
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Very nice. Works perfectly for what I was wanting with a modal.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new `Route` for your modal and keep it outside of your `Switch`. This way regular navigation will still apply, and you can also render the modal on top of what is rendered in your `Switch`.

**Example**

```
function Home() {
  return <div> Home </div>;
}

function MyRoute() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MyRoute</h1>
      <Link to="/myroute/edit"> Edit </Link>
      <Route
        path="/myroute/edit"
        render={({ history }) => (
          <ModalComponent history={history}>
            Welcome to the MyRoute edit screen
          </ModalComponent>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

class ModalComponent extends React.Component {
  onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal isOpen>
        <h1> {this.props.children} </h1>
        <Link to="/myroute" onClick={this.onClick}>
          Back
        </Link>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
        <Link to="/myroute"> My Route </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/myroute" component={MyRoute} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
Modal.setAppElement(rootElement);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I implemented this and it gives me error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` , when I press the button.