# How to close a modal on browser back button using react-router-dom?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` and what I want is to be able to close a Modal when I click browser back button.

Also, in my scenario, the modal component is not the part of `Switch`. So how can I close the modal.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you please put some code

Comment: @OwaisLatif I'm sorry I can't because it's all scattered. My question is very similar to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381060/react-router-dom-v4-handle-browser-back-button

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use something like this to detect the press of the Back button.

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
  window.onpopstate = e => {
    
  }
}
```

And then, depending on your modal (Bootstrap or something else) you can call `.hide()` or `.close()`.

Comment: Then when I close the Modal, how do I disable the back button in that case?

Comment: You mean the other way around? You need to know (in your state) if the modal is closed and when "onpopstate" fires again you can e.preventDefault() it. But it may not work in every browser.

Comment: No I mean, when I press the back button of Browser. I want the modal to be closed and not move back to previous screen

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple hook called `useAppendLocationState` that does all the job:

```
function SomeComponent() {
    const [showModal , appendShowModal ] = useAppendLocationState('showModal');

    return (
        <div>
            <div>...some view...</div>
            <button onClick={() => appendOpenModal(true)}>open modal</button>
            {showModal && <SomeModal closeHandler={() => window.history.back()} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

`useAppendLocationState` returns a array with two entries just like `useState`, The first entry is the state prop value coming from **browser location state** and the second entry is a method that pushes a new item to **browser history** with new state prop appended to current location state.

here is our `useAppendLocationState` definition:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

export function useAppendLocationState(key) {
    if (!key) throw new Error("key cannot be null or empty value")

    const history = useHistory()
    const currentLocationState = history.location.state;

    const appendStateItemValue = (value) => {
        const newLocationState = { ...currentLocationState }
        newLocationState[key] = value;
        history.push(history.location.pathname, newLocationState)
    }

    const stateItemValue = history.location.state && history.location.state[key]


    return [stateItemValue, appendStateItemValue]
}

export default useAppendLocationState
```

Comment: I had used a similar solution myself as well but has several drawbacks too. Example: User opens /home then /home#yourmodal then closes the site. The next time they open that page /home#yourmodal from history they don't see the modal anymore, or if that key is present in another page example /login#yourmodal and the props are missing

Answer (score -8):

Have you tried: ComponentWillUnmount?

Comment: Use ComponentWillUnmount how?